# JOptionPane how to exit code once cancel button clicked

Tags: java

I am trying to create a chat bot that continues to asks question about entered topics until the users clicks the cancel button. Being new to coding i am not exactly sure how to check is the cancel button has been clicked but as far as Ive read it will return 'null' once the button has been clicked. My code below i think is close but produces an error message whenever i go to cancel.

Code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi! This is your chatbot. We will now begin the input taking phase");

        String topicOne = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter topic 1");
        String topicTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter topic 2");
        String topicThree = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter topic 3");


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for the topics, we will now begin the chatting phase");

        String response = "hello";
        boolean questionMark;
        boolean containsTopicOne;
        boolean containsTopicTwo;
        boolean containsTopicThree;

        while (response != null) {
            response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please tell me more about " + topicOne + ", " + topicTwo + ", " + topicThree + "...");
            questionMark = response.indexOf('?') >= 0;
            containsTopicOne = response.indexOf(topicOne) >= 0;
            containsTopicTwo = response.indexOf(topicTwo) >= 0;
            containsTopicThree = response.indexOf(topicThree) >= 0;

            if (questionMark == true) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'll be the one asking the questions!");
                questionMark = false;
                containsTopicOne = false;
                containsTopicTwo = false;
                containsTopicThree = false;
            }
            else if (containsTopicOne == true || containsTopicTwo == true || containsTopicThree == true){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NIce to know!");
                questionMark = false;
                containsTopicOne = false;
                containsTopicTwo = false;
                containsTopicThree = false;
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stay on topic!");
                questionMark = false;
                containsTopicOne = false;
                containsTopicTwo = false;
                containsTopicThree = false;
            }
        }
}
```

Error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at actionPerformed.main(actionPerformed.java:31)

Any help would be great thanks or advice to streamline code.

Comment: `NullPointerException at actionPerformed.main(actionPerformed.java:31)` - you have a NPE at line 31. Figure out which variable is null and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample Yes/No:

```
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?", "WARNING",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // yes selected
} else {
    // no selected
}
```